# XML node update Error- java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Permission denied)

Tags: parsing, groovy

I am trying to update and save an existing XML file using “new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filepath))).print(xmlParse)” And every time I am getting error on file reading “java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Permission denied)" on file.

My Code is:

```
def filepath = "X:/XXX/XX/abc.xml"
def xml = readFile(filepath)
def xmlParse = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
xmlParse.project.each { A ->

if (A.@name == XXXXX){ 
      A.Branch.each { B ->
         if (B.@id == XXXXX){ 
         Do somthing....
         B.@id = YYYY  
        }
      }
new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filepath))).print(xmlParse)
```

Error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: X:\XXX\XX\abc.xml (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
```

Comment: Error is clear. Please check if the file exists in the given path. Or check the permission to write.

Comment: Actually this is a case !! file is available at path and we have given appropriate permissions to the account. XML parser is doing well here and we can read the file. But mentioned error is coming on xml file modification on "new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filepath))).print(xmlParse) " command.